# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform in .NET 6.0 C# library

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-6.0, sqlclient

When I run the C# .NET 6.0 library from my console program, I havn't  problem with `System.Data.SqlClient` or Microsoft.Data.SqlClient i tested with two DLL , but if I call the dll with another `.exe` program in .NET 6.0, I get an exception for two dll System.Data.SqlClient` or Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and also  oledb dll.

> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

My code:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
    {
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        connection.Open();

        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                return true;
            }                               
        }
    }
}
```

[My CSProj file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIkSr.png)

[Exeption](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXS6U.png)

Comment: And what's the platform? You probably need to use Microsoft.Data.SqlClient instead. It's cross-platform where the other is, I think, Windows-specific.

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: @John i use framework .net 6.0 to build Library for Windows x64

Comment: I have  installed Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0 the last version in nuget

Comment: No one should have to read the comments to understand the question. Don't add information in comments that should have been in the question from the outset. Edit the question and provide ALL the relevant information. You should spend some time in the Help Center to learn how to write a good question.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718924/fixing-platformnotsupportedexception-when-referencing-system-data-sqlclient-from) seems relevant and suggests that using the other package will work. You should have found that for yourself before posting a question at all, given that it was the first result when I searched the web for "sqlclient PlatformNotSupportedException". You should never post a question here without having searched thoroughly first.

Comment: @John I did a search and I tried several proposed solutions but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that the same issue exists when using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient?

Comment: I guess that even though you have installed the Microsoft.Data.SqlClient package, you are still using the System.Data.SqlClient namespace.

Comment: I 'am using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0 and ihave the same exeption and i havn' t System.data.sSqlClent  System.PlatformNotSupportedException : 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.'

Comment: [earlier dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72556321/exception-when-using-microsoft-data-sqlclient-ado-net-with-project-net-core-6-0)

Comment: So have you searched all source files in your library and your .NET 6.0 console program (both of them) for any references to `System.Data.SqlClient`?

Comment: I checked and I don't have System.Data.SqlClient neither has my console nor my library project

Comment: I tired to use  System.Data.OleDb but i have same problem

Comment: Can you post the .csproj file so we can see what packages are being referenced?

Comment: @brent.reynolds I added my csproj .

Comment: Nothing in there is dependent on `System.Data.SqlClient`, unless it's the redacted package pulling it in.

Comment: @brent.reynolds first time i used System.Data.SqlClient and i change to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0

Comment: @brent.reynolds I added my exception Screenshot

Comment: I change from System.Data.SqlClient to Microsoft.Data.SqlClient and to System.Data.OleDb and i have same exeption PlatformNotSupportedException is not supported on this platform

Comment: You can see from your screenshot that the exception is being thrown from `iYDA.Agent.Validation(Cassiopae).dll` Whatever that is, it is probably where your dependency on `System.Data.SqlClient` is coming from.

Answer (score 2):

For me, adding the target OS platform in the Server.Proj.cs file fixed the issue.

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>ubuntu.22.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
```

Use "dotnet --info" in terminal to find you target OS platform ("ubuntu.22.04-x64" for me), then add it to your proj.cs files.

> Runtime Environment:
> OS Name:     linuxmint
> OS Version:  21.1
> OS Platform: Linux
> RID:         ubuntu.22.04-x64
> Base Path:   /usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/7.0.109/

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>ubuntu.22.04-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Basically, from what I gathered after a few hours of research...

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient has multiple DLL's for different target platforms. For some reason, the incorrect one is being loaded. You can specify explicity which dll to load with the method I provided.

Comment: Well this isn't super awesome if it's a distributed project but at least now I have a lead